# Trying to auto fill up a database table concerning mobile phones brands and their models

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, ssms

I want to fill up a database table concerning mobile phones and their models from a website like gsmarena, only the brand and the model. Am using microsoft sql server, but to fill it i think i can do that with a php crawler, is there any alternative or any tip to do that easily?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GSMArena doesn't seem to offer an API it seems, so there's no other chance for you than to scrape their website. However, [that might be illegal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping#Legal_issues). Ask them first.

Comment: I will do that for sure before retrieving any data from any website.